# $\lim_{x \to 0 }|x| = 0$

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

Given $\epsilon > 0$ we want to $\delta > 0$ such as $|x - 0| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(0)| < \epsilon $.

How
\begin{align}
|x| = 
\begin{cases}
x, \text{ if } x > 0\\ 
-x, \text{ if } x < 0
\end{cases}
\end{align}

From desigualities we have

if  $x > 0$ : $|x - 0| < \epsilon$

and if $x < 0 : $

$|-x - 0 | < \epsilon \Rightarrow |-1||x - 0| < \epsilon \Rightarrow |x - 0| < \epsilon$

Because this, we take it $\delta = \epsilon$.

So, $|x - 0|<\delta \Rightarrow |x - 0|<\epsilon$.

Therefore, for definition $\lim_{x \to 0 }|x| = 0$

It's right?

> With the hints I rewrited like this:
> Given $\epsilon > 0$ we want to $\delta > 0$ such as $|x - 0| < \delta
> > \Rightarrow ||x| - 0| < \epsilon $.
>
> As $||x| - 0| = |x|$ we have that $|x| < \epsilon$ so we take it
> $\delta = \epsilon$.
> So, $|x - 0|<\delta \Rightarrow ||x| -
> 0|<\epsilon$.
>
> Therefore, for definition $\lim_{x \to 0 }|x| = 0$

Comment: Shortly, $$|x|<\delta=\epsilon\implies ||x|-0|<\epsilon.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong definition. What you need should be the definition of $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$, not $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=f(0)$. The latter is the continuity of $f$ at $x=0$. The function $f(x)=|x|$ is indeed continuous at $0$ though.

The estimate you want should be
$$
||x|-0|<\epsilon.
$$

You don't need to discuss two cases. Simply observe that
$$
||x|-0|=|x|
$$

Comment: Strictly speaking, the function is not defined at $x=0$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: yes, when one talks about $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$, the function $f$ is *not necessarily* defined at $x=0$. All one needs is $x=0$ being a limit point of the domain of $f$.

Comment: You needn't tell me. As $|0|$ is not defined, continuity cannot be assessed.

Comment: Hmm. I see your point. OP does not include the point zero into their $|x|$. Fair enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let us use a standart definition of a limit of a function: $\forall \varepsilon>0\; \exists \delta:\forall x\in\stackrel{\circ}{U}_{\delta}(x_{0})\Rightarrow |f(x) - L|<\varepsilon$. For given function $f(x) = |x|$ we have $x_{0}=0$. Let us take $\delta = \varepsilon/2$. Then indeed $|x - 0 | \leq |\delta| = \varepsilon/2 < \varepsilon$. Because of arbitrary choice of $\varepsilon$, we have that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} |x| = 0$.